# Tycho mirror overrides instead of synchronize

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, p2

I set up a [project](https://gist.github.com/andrask/11366649) to mirror Eclipse repositories that I use most often based on the tutorial from [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html).

The issue is every time I start a build, the `target` directory is cleared by the plugin and the whole mirroring process starts from scratch. I run it with `mvn package` so clean is not among the targets.

Is there any way to tell tycho to use the existing data and not start with wiping out everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the `eclipse-repository` packaging includes `clean` in the default lifecycle (i.e. in your case `package`) is a [know problem in Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399756).

To avoid this problem, don't use `eclipse-repository` for mirroring a remote repository. Instead, use the packaging `pom` and configure the goals that you want explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. I wanted to use eclipse-repository to make the mirror available through nexus. Do you have any ideas how I could still to that?

Comment: The packaging type `pom` doesn't have a main artifact, but you can have the zipped p2 repository deployed by [making it an attached artifact of the project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html)